# Looking for a data mapping format with inheritance

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, inheritance, serialization, xml-serialization

Right now, I have many **XML**'s describing all game objects, with its properties set. For example:

```
<gameObject id="commonEnemy">
    ...
    <data>
        <life>100</life>
        <speed>12</speed>
    </data>
    <tags>
        <tag>KILLABLE</tag>
        <tag>COLLIDABLE</tag>
    </tags>
    ...
</gameObject>
```

All files have different *"components"* (like **data** and **tags** in the example above). There are nearly a thousands of these files, consuming much disk-space. But since some **gameObject** *"share"* some properties with others, I can make a *default* file and inherit other files from it, thus changing only what is needed. Something like:

```
<gameObject id="badassEnemy" import="commonEnemy">
    ...
    <data>
        <life>200</life> <!-- I'm increasing the life -->
    </data>
    <tags>
        <tag>KILLABLE</tag>
        <!-- And is not more collidable. Totally weird XML syntax, but just to make a point -->
        remove <tag>COLLIDABLE</tag>
    </tags>
    ...
</gameObject>
```

But as far as I know, XML don't support by default inheritance, nor it is very friendly of merging nodes.

**What I need** is some format which allows me to:

- Inherit from one object
- Add a simple type and array type
- Modify a simple type and array type
- Delete a simple type and array type

The array should be accesed by index or something like that.
I looked on the **[diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)** format, but I can't use that, because if I ever change the default type, all the children will be broken.
I know that a **custom binary** file would be the way to go to save up disk space, but the object **must be** editable with a simple notepad application.
I also looked on **JSON** and **YAML**, neither of them seems to have inheritance in mind.

Is there some data format which allows me to do what I want? Or I need to write my own data format and parser?

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?  I have the same issue but must use XML,  we have several dynamically genrated documents in XML that share lots of common content, would love to be able to override a base document.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about disk space consider zip it:) XML's are reduced greatly by archiver.

It is hard to achieve inheriting but possible but don't think very efficient and it means that all those XML's share the same structure (and tag names).

Then you have XML a and XML b and iterating over b and adding it's children to a. You have to check if the tag exist if not add without further checks, but if you will find the same you have to merge them (iteration).

Are you bind to the XML format? Maybe is worth to check if the conversion is appriopriate (to another format like JSON you've mentioned. Building tool to convert it is much quicker than building functionality that you require based on XML.

Best regards

Comment: But does JSON provide inheritance?

Comment: I'm not sure it does but it could be added.